# Crash due to Hierarchy view only on Nougat

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat

I am facing a crash of my Android app with the stack trace below.

What puzzles me is that the same code with the same variable values (tried with the debugger) does not crash on **Android 8 and 9, only on 7.0 / 7.1**. The reason is `self-explanatory:` there's some redrawing triggered from a class (VoipCallsManager) that is not done over the UI thread, but why this is not triggered on newer Android?

```
E/FatalExceptionKalliope: Uncaught Exception
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6898)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1083)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5205)
        at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:13660)
        at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13624)
        at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13608)
        at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:531)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageDrawable(AppCompatImageView.java:100)
        at it.myapp.MainActivity.onSoftPhoneChangeSettings(MainActivity.java:2582)
        at it.myapp.stefanotest.VoipCallsManager.isActive(VoipCallsManager.java:187)
        at it.myapp.call.MakeCall.executeUseCase(MakeCall.java:53)
        at it.myapp.call.MakeCall.executeUseCase(MakeCall.java:15)
        at it.myapp.UseCase.run(UseCase.java:40)
        at it.myapp.UseCaseHandler$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
2019-02-12 19:09:52.340 6961-7055/it.myapp I/intouchste: Uncaught Exception Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Comment: the error means that you have tried manipulating UI from non-UI thread. Probably in newer versions of Android some callbacks have been put on non-UI threads.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace indicates UseCase is a thread and started by the ThreadPoolExecutor, so it is the correct behavior to throw the exception. You can wrap that code with runOnUiThread() to avoid this problem.

However why it doesn't crash on other versions? If you really want to dig to the bottom, you can make a deliberate crash at that place, e.g., divide by zero. So you can have a stack trace on other devices. You can compare with the one you listed here, probably you can find it is not started in a thread.

Comment: Hello, i tried with a debugger and the stack trace is identical.